# Spring version change causes RESTful function to break

Tags: java, spring, rest

In upgrading my application to use the newest version of Spring available to me (3.1.1), I have found that one of my REST calls throws 404 error (when it used to be perfectly successful). I have verified that switching back to the old libraries (3.0.3) work, and back to the new ones fail, all without changing my code.

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/group/{groupId}/template")
public class TemplateController extends AbstractController {
    ...

    @RequestMapping(value="/{templateId}", method=RequestMethod.GET) @ResponseBody
    public Template getTemplate(ServletWebRequest request, 
            @PathVariable("groupId") int groupId, 
            @PathVariable("templateId") int templateId) throws Exception {
        ...
    }

    ...

    @RequestMapping(value="/{templateId}", method=RequestMethod.DELETE) @ResponseBody
    public Task getTemplate(ServletWebRequest request, 
            @PathVariable("groupId") int groupId, 
            @PathVariable("templateId") int templateId) throws Exception {
        ...
    }

    ...
}
```

I threw the GET method in there just for comparison, and it works. However, when I make the request for the DELETE method (again, which used to work), I get an error back in the log stating:

```
WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/*appname*/group/1/template/group/1/template/1] in DispatcherServlet with name '*appname*'
```

Now, the error is obviously correct, I don't have any URI with that mapping, but why is it trying to find that mapping instead of the specified one (`/*appname*/group/1/template/1`)?

Comment: I couldn't replicate this behavior at all with Spring MVC 3.1.1(with both GET and DELETE calls), can you please check if the client is not sending something different ?

Comment: @Biju Kunjummen I'm using Linux's curl to send these calls, so a client issue shouldn't be the problem. Plus, I have other controllers that match this functionality, just for different items, and they work fine. I even took the DELETE function from a working controller and pasted it into this one, and got the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm still not sure why I was getting the error that appeared, so insight into the inner workings of Spring would be appreciated, but I did figure out what was causing it. The only thing different about that method as opposed to the others was that it was throwing an exception while the others weren't. After I commented out my ExceptionHandler, the function registered correctly.

```
@ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
public Map<String, String> handleExceptions(Exception e) {
    ...
}
```

I still don't really know why this caused it to error, but ironically, this was the reason that I upgraded the libraries in the first place: so that the exception handling would work correctly. After I added `@ResponseBody` to the function (which I meant to do in the first place), everything worked out alright.

Answer (score 0):

Its treating / in the value as a root try mapping by removing the / in the value for the method @RequestMapping.

```
@RequestMapping(value="{templateId}", method=RequestMethod.DELETE) @ResponseBody
    public Task getTemplate(ServletWebRequest request, 
            @PathVariable("groupId") int groupId, 
            @PathVariable("templateId") int templateId) throws Exception {
        ...
    }
```

Comment: It was a good thought, but I ended up with the same, exact result. I tried to follow how [Spring does it](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html) (see section 16.3.2). Also, why would the GET work with it, but not the DELETE?